# CSS Dropdown not working in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a CSS dropdown.  It works fine in Chrome, but the links drop down at the left side of the page in Firefox.  Any ideas? Thanks!

CSS

```
 .links  ul ul { /* lists within lists... */
  position: absolute; /* place them over the top of everything */
  display: none; /* hide 'em */
  width: 180px;
}

 .links li:hover ul { /* when list items are hovered over, do this to lists contained         within them... */
  display: block; /* show 'em */
}
```

HTML

```
<nav class="links">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="./html/management.html">Management Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="./html/schedule.html">Schedule</a></li>
        <li><a href="./html/lyrics.html">Lyric Checker</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Calendar</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Resources &#x25bc;</a>
            <ul class="links">
                <li><a href="html/how_to_itunes.html">iTunes Tips</a></li>
                <li><a href="html/how_to_simian_format.html">Simian Format</a></li>
                <li><a href="html/how_to_simian_liner.html">Simian Liner</a></li>
                <li><a href="html/how_to_news.html">News at &#58;55</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Works fine. Probably something else breaks it. http://jsfiddle.net/04zL9p0y/

Comment: I assume there is more CSS than what you've posted.